# connection to ms sql server with php failed

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection

I want to connect to SQL Server database using php and I couldn't do that. I receive 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()`. I have followed some guidelines but didn't help much. For instance, I followed this guid line 
http://forum.ragezone.com/f724/get-wamp-work-mssql-673301/

Does anyone has an idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is mssql extension enabled?

Answer (score 0):

try this code to connect mssql.

```
$server = 'KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS';
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
```

more information is here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

also you can find Mssql tutorial [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()` error when I run this.